# Remote or wireless access to XBMC (android box or RPi) from Win8 PC

Tags: wireless-networking, android, raspberry-pi, kodi

I am trying to gather information on setting up an XBMC Android TV box (or using RPi) and I am looking to what I want to do with it since it will replace me home video server.

With My home server I could do two things that I wish to do with my new device. I had on utorrent on my computer to monitor a specific folder in dropbox for .torrent files. Whenever I was at work or anywhere and I found a .torrent I needed I would upload it to that specific folder in dropbox and my utorrent would download it directly to my video server Until I got home and ready to watch.
Similarly I had wireless access from my computer to my server where I could transfer video files directly to it.

I want to replicate this using my Android box or RPi and XBMC. I know XBMC torrent plugins exist, but do they offer folder monitoring? If so how may I upload the .torrent files remotely?

Also how can I have access to the device's files through the network?

Comment: Not sure I'd try to do those things with Android. You can most likely do it in some way, although it might be a bit tricky. Personally, I'd grab a *Raspberry Pi* for around 35$ and use that for all such things. Power consumption will be very low, even if it runs 24/7.

Comment: I did not find any information for the Raspberry Pi either. Also I found less customization and guides for setting up XBMC on Raspberry pi so decided to go with Android Box solution. Still did not buy anything though because I want to complete my research before I start my building.

Comment: There are [premade images](http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/) available for Raspberry Pi. Specifically **RASPBMC** might be exactly what you're looking for. You just download the image, move it to an SD card and you're done. This is a minimal system that will boot right into XBMC. Behind the scenes its a standard ARM based Unix system, so you can install other things like a torrent client through apt-get and use cronjobs to schedule things.

Comment: Downside of course, the RPi won't run Android apps without jumping hoops. :)

Comment: Yeah, one of the benefits of Android Boxes is Android apps (and emulators :D ) Can you give me a guide on doing what I am asking and for setting the XBMC as an answer?

Comment: While I've setup multiple RPi systems, I'm not 100% proficient with using DropBox on Unix, shell scripting and the like, so I'll leave that for someone else to answer. You could however update your actual question to better reflect that you're looking for a minimal system (either Android or RPi; make it clear that it doesn't have to be Android) and what you'd like it to do. Also there are emulators available for RPi as well. :)